# Access List of Items from cURL Result

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, unix, curl

If u go to this url : http://artii.herokuapp.com/fonts_list, you will see a list of 417 items on the list.

I'm trying to create a variable to store/access those list.

I could not get it to work.

```
fontList=$(curl http://artii.herokuapp.com/fonts_list)
fontListCount=$(curl http://artii.herokuapp.com/fonts_list | wc -l)

for i in $(seq 1 $fontListCount);
do
    echo -e "I like this font --> " fontList[$i]
done
```

I kept getting

```
I like this font -->  fontList[1]
...
I like this font -->  fontList[417]
```

Any hints on how to do it ?

Comment: when i access that page, i just get ```Application error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command
heroku logs --tail```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with the assumption that the result is, in fact, one font name per line, you can use a single call to `readarray`:

```
readarray -t fontList < <(curl http://artii.herokuapp.com/fonts_list)
```

Then

```
for i in "${fontList[@]}"; do
  echo "I like this font --> $i"
done
```

Comment: You're very very good ! Works on first try will accept this answer.

Answer (score 1):

In general, when expanding the value of variables, you want to surround them with `${...}`, otherwise bash interprets the variable names as normal strings:

```
for i in $(seq 1 $fontListCount);
do
    echo -e "I like this font --> " ${fontList[$i]}
done
```